# Showing block cursor in insert mode for VIM - only works after opening VIM twice (in xterm)

Tags: ubuntu, vim, wsl-2, windows-terminal

When I pop open Windows Terminal (running Ubuntu on WSL2) - the first time I open VIM, it doesn't honor my block cursor settings (where it should show a block when I'm in normal mode). If I then close VIM and open it again... it works as I expect for all future use... until I close terminal and open at a later time, or when I open a new tab even.

I have this in my ~/.vimrc (on Ubuntu running on WSL2 with Windows Terminal).

```
if $TERM_PROGRAM =~ "iTerm"
    let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7" " Vertical bar in insert mode
    let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7" " Block in normal mode
elseif $TERM =~ "xterm-256color"
    let &t_SI = "\<Esc>[6 q"
    let &t_SR = "\<Esc>[4 q"
    let &t_EI = "\<Esc>[2 q"
endif
```

The elsif clause is the relevant chunk (the if clause is for when I'm on my mac).

Am I missing something that would cause the first use to ignore those settings for the cursor... but would work fine thereafter?

I also noted that if, in that first use, I run the command `:echo &t_SI`, then it starts working immediately as well...

VIM version 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding this to run when ZSH is loading solves the problem, though I'd love to better understand why it works.

`echo -ne "\e[2 q"`

I found it in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/hr0rf1/vim_in_windows_terminal/fy17dyz?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) reddit answer.